# Akka ask Broadcast

Tags: scala, routes, akka

I have an akka 2.0 round-robin router. Now I need to broadcast a message to all routees and await the answers from all of them. I did not found a way to do so yet. First I had a list of actors that I passed to the router, but now I need to load them from my application.conf. Is there a way to await all messages of a Broadcast? It would be fine as well if I could get the number of routees from the conf flie.

Comment: If I were you I'd look at the ScatterGatherFirstCompletedRouter and create a new one that does that ScatterGather and then send a pull request and sign the CLA :-)

Comment: Viktor, In that case what would the semantics of the reply message be ?  just Iterable[<what the individual actors reply>]  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the number of routees, then you would normally just count the number of answers received. However, you may want to account for a timeout, especially if your actors are running distributed because there is no guarantee that messages really get delivered.

Comment: You are right but at this point I really need all answers. If one fails the whole requst fails.

Comment: The basic algorithm to do this is shown in the tutorial at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html . The Master class works in almost exactly this way. The only missing bit is a timeout for all operations to complete. But I guess this would only be necessary if your actors are truly distributed across several JVMs and/or systems.

Comment: To get the timeout implemented for the Master actor in this tutorial, you could setup a scheduler (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/scheduler.html) and send a custom Timeout message to the Master actor.

Comment: I solved the problem with ducktyping and check for the number of routees. So I will accept your answer.